# Vertica - Work around for using WITH with INSERT statement

Tags: sql, sql-insert, common-table-expression, vertica

I have a SQL query like

```
with subtable as (
................
)
select * 
from subtable
```

I wanted to insert the records from the select statement into a table. looking for something like :

```
with subtable as (......)
insert into newtable 
select * 
from subtable
```

However, in Vertica, INSERT cannot be used with the WITH ( CTE) statements.

Is there any work around for this?

Thanks for the help

Comment: You might use a view instead.

Comment: why do you want to use the `with` clause when you can just `insert into newtable ( ... <select/union here> ... )`?

Comment: Mark the right answer ! @woot - delivered !

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`with` is part of the select.

```
insert into newtable 
with subtable as (......) 
select * 
from subtable
```

Comment: Would love to hear why I was downvoted. This is correct for Vertica.

Answer (score 0):

I can only agree to what woot said. 
In Vertica, the common table expression is supported in the SELECT statement - not in any DML statement. That's also what the ANSI standard intended.
If your point is to have the data bit at the top of the script and not "hidden" by the INSERT INTO foo line before, then you can (but still with one line before the WITH clause):

```
CREATE LOCAL TEMPORARY TABLE foo(id,ts,name,exp) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS AS 
          SELECT 1,'2016-12-13 10:11'::TIMESTAMP,'Moshe',1
UNION ALL SELECT 2,'2016-12-13 12:12'::TIMESTAMP,'Karl' ,2
UNION ALL SELECT 3,'2016-12-13 13:12'::TIMESTAMP,'Karl' ,2
UNION ALL SELECT 4,'2016-12-13 14:09'::TIMESTAMP,'Moshe',2
UNION ALL SELECT 5,'2016-12-13 18:07'::TIMESTAMP,'Karl' ,2
KSAFE 0;
```

Marco the Sane